# Finding the sum of a field in a linked table per group with additional search criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

My actual tables are much more complex but here is a simplified example of the problem I am trying to work out.

- Table contact: ContactID, ContactName, Pending
- Table purchase: PurchaseID, ContactID, Amount, Pending, Date
- Table contact_purchase_link: ContactID, PurchaseID (although it may seem like the link table is not necessary in this simplified example it is necessary in the large table schema)

Here is the query that I currently have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact.ContactID,
                ( SELECT SUM(Amount)
                  FROM purchase
                  WHERE purchase.ContactID = contact.ContactID
                    AND purchase.Pending = 0
                ) totalpurchase 
FROM contact
INNER JOIN ( contact_purchase_link JOIN purchase
             ON (contact_purchase_link.PurchaseID = purchase.PurchaseID
           ))
USING (ContactID)  
WHERE purchase.Date > '2013-12-06' AND
  AND contact.Pending =0
```

The problem is that I want the totalpurchase (the sum of the amount field) to be limited to the search criteria of the purchase table - meaning the query should only return the sum of the purchases after the specified date per contact. I think in order to use a group by clause the query would have to be based off the purchase table but I need the query to use the contact table so that all contacts are listed with their total purchase amounts and other relevant client data.
Is there any way to do this within one query?

To further clarify:

This query is being generated as part of a search engine. An example of why a query like this would be done is if a user wanted to generate a contact list of lastnames starting with A with purchases of a specific item or as in this example of purchases for a specific date.  So that in general the query would have to generate a list of all contacts and their data (with possible search criteria on the type of contact such as all lastnames starting with 'A' etc.) and the query can also include search criteria on the purchase table such as the date of the purchase and whether the purchase was for specific items etc.

I am trying to add in the option to also list the sum of the purchases for the contact however that sum has to be limited to the search criteria for the purchase table as well and not the sum of all the contacts purchases.

Comment: I suggest that you check your query (as posted) for syntax errors.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here. You have a link table, but in your current query `purchase` is joined directly to `contact` in the `SELECT SUM(Amount)` part. Could you add sample data and expected results? To help clarify your question, the sample data should include a couple of `purchase` records that won't be included in the `totalpurchase` amount.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed the syntax errors in the query. This query is a simplified query of a much larger more complex query generated by a search engine. The reason I left the direct link from the contact to the purchase table is because in the real query it is directly linked to a default contact in the purchase table. However I wanted to leave in the join to the contact_purchase_link table because it is a necessary part of the more complex query and I need an answer that includes that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to move the date comparison inside the first subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact.ContactID,
                ( SELECT SUM(Amount)
                  FROM purchase
                  WHERE purchase.ContactID = contact.ContactID
                    AND purchase.Pending = 0
                    AND purchase.Date > '2013-12-06'
                ) totalpurchase 
FROM contact
INNER JOIN ( contact_purchase_link JOIN purchase
             ON (contact_purchase_link.PurchaseID = purchase.PurchaseID
           )
USING (ContactID)  
WHERE purchase.Date > '2013-12-06'
  AND contact.Pending =0
```

But the comments are right - I corrected a couple of what appears to be syntax errors, and I'm not sure about the join to `contact_purchase_link`. Improve your question and my answer will be less like guesswork.

Comment: Thanks @boisvert you understood the question correctly and your answer would give the desired results. One problem though is since this query is being generated as part of a search engine the amount of search criteria is user based (specific dates, over a certain amount etc.). With the query you suggest I would have to include all the search criteria for the purchase table in the sub-select to generate the total purchase amount (and in other similar sub-selects such as max purchase) is that efficient? is there any way to do this without adding the search criteria to each sub query?

Comment: @ssp, an alternative would be using group by. But efficiency is something that is difficult to judge in the abstract. You could try the query, check the time taken, the execution plan, try alternatives and compare speed and execution plan for that, then add some well-chosen indexes. But if you find the answer helpful, then vote it up or accept it ; if you find the query slow, ask a second question, trying to get very specific and taking in the advice of other commentators.

Comment: I agree I'll just have to check how long the queries take using this method I was just hoping there was a query that would seem less cumbersome. I originally thought group by would be more efficient but I couldn't figure out how to get a query that would work and give the results that I want. If you could give me an example I'd appreciate it.